# In dataweave How to fetch year and month from string "2018-07-30T16:39:12"

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Need to retrieve year and month from string "2018-07-30T16:39:12"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the String to a LocalDateTime first using the ISO8601 date format you have above. Then you can access year and month. Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var myDateString = "2018-07-30T16:39:12"
type LocalDateFormat = LocalDateTime { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" }
var myDate = myDateString as LocalDateFormat 
---
{
  year: myDate.year,
  month: myDate.month,
  day: myDate.day,
  hour: myDate.hour,
  minutes: myDate.minutes,
  seconds: myDate.seconds,
  milliseconds: myDate.milliseconds,
  nanoseconds: myDate.nanoseconds,
  quarter: myDate.quarter,
  dayOfWeek: myDate.dayOfWeek,
  dayOfYear: myDate.dayOfYear,
  offsetSeconds: myDate.offsetSeconds
}
```

Comment: He's earned the tick!

Comment: Hi @Ryan, If i have date in the (2018-07-30T16:39:12+00:00) format then the current formatting is failing. Can you please help me with the correct format here?